# What's wrong with this simple code using strings, malloc and strcat?

Tags: c, string, malloc, arrays

A `char**` always confuses me.
The following code generates a segmentation fault.
Explain please...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char** nameList;
    nameList = malloc(4*sizeof(char*));
    nameList[0] = malloc(12); //not sure if needed but doesn't work either
    nameList[0] = "Hello "; 
    printf("%s  ",nameList[0]);// even this statement isn't executed
    strcat(nameList[0], "World");
    printf("%s ",nameList[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind `malloc` doesn't zero the memory or anything.

Comment: zero the memory means?

Comment: Fill it with 0s (which, if you'll remember, are the value of null characters).

Comment: You mean I've to add a '\0' character manually to the end?

Comment: Use calloc instead of malloc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code exhibits undefined behavior by writing to read-only storage, and also attempting to write past the end of it.

Your `malloc` idea was a step in the right direction. However, you should use `strcpy` to copy `"Hello"` into the newly allocated memory. In addition, you need to consider the size of the string that you are planning to append, and the null terminator when calculating the size of the dynamic allocation.

Obviously, you also need to free all your allocated memory at the end of your program:

```
char** nameList;
nameList = malloc(4*sizeof(char*));
nameList[0] = malloc(12);
strcpy(nameList[0], "Hello ");
printf("%s  ",nameList[0]);
strcat(nameList[0], "World"); // You were strcat-ing into a wrong element
printf("%s ",nameList[0]);
free(nameList[0]);
free(nameList);
```

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/DoHRMR).

Comment: need to free or should free?

Comment: And is there a way to keep concatenating to a single single and keep increasing it's length on the go? In my real project, I don't know the length of nameList[i] strings beforehand...

Comment: @BlueFlame Technically, it's a "should", of course. But in practice it's almost inevitably turns into a "need to" :)

Comment: @BlueFlame The `nameList[0] = "Hello"` fails because it replaces the pointer to the allocated dynamic memory with a constant "string" memory. You can't `strcat` into that memory, because it's read-only.

Comment: @BlueFlame You can expand the string as you go by calling `realloc` on it, passing the new size. For example, to append `"XYZ"` to `"Hello World"` that you have there you'd need to call `NameList[0] = realloc(NameList[0], strlen(NameList[0])+strlen("XYZ")+1)`. After that you'd be able to `strcat` into the re-allocated space.

Answer (score 3):

After `nameList = malloc(4*sizeof(char*));` you have:
   nameList[0] = trash
   nameList[1] = trash
   nameList[2] = trash
   nameList[3] = trash

After `nameList[0] = "Hello ";` you have
  nameList[0] = "Hello"
  nameList[1] = trash
  nameList[2] = trash
  nameList[3] = trash

So when you do `strcat(nameList[1], "World");` it's very likely you'll get a segfault, because nameList[1] can point to anywhere in memory.

Comment: oops, I meant to keep nameList[0] instead of nameList[1]. the edited code generates the same error.

Comment: @BlueFlame see dasblinkenlight's answer, that's the one that will help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Before using double ptrs, get code that uses a single ptr to work.  Also, you don't want to "overprogram" simple code.  However, if you want to program the usage of a double ptr, start with this code and modify to use double ptrs.

```
int main()
{
        char *nameList;

        nameList = malloc(12);   // point nameList to 12 bytes of storage

        strncpy(nameList, "Hello \0", 7);
        printf("%s\n",nameList);   // notice no space, its already after hello

        strncat(nameList, "World", 5);
        printf("%s\n",nameList);

        free(nameList);

        return 0;
}
```